# How to add array in Spinner that is generating at run time Java

Tags: java, android, arrays, spinner, android-relativelayout

hi i am trying to create spinner at run time my code is,

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
final Spinner[] Sp = new Spinner[10];
Sp[count] = new Spinner(this);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    (int) LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    (int) LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            param.leftMargin = 25;
            param.topMargin = 50;
            Sp[count].setPadding(5, 23, 5, 5);
            Sp[count].setLayoutParams(param);
            layout.addView(Sp[count]);
```

i have **String[] data** how to add its value in spinner dropdown ?

Hopes for your suggestion

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like below

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        Sp[count].setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Chandra i am getting checkbox like [v]alue in this way how can i format it ?

Comment: Sorry ,i did not get you.Please clarify.

Comment: i wanna say that checkbox iscreating bu text of checkbox overlap on its box

Comment: you are using spinner not the checkbox in your code.

Comment: Ohh sorry i missunderstod